# Are all refugees vetted as per these guidelines?

Tags: united-states, law, refugees

I came across this page on the white house website that lists the screening process of refugees in the US:

https://www.whitehouse.gov/blog/2015/11/20/infographic-screening-process-refugee-entry-united-states

Do all those hundred thousand refugees go through this rigorous process?

If so what is the need for a stronger refugee laws and control? Is it because this process isn't enough?

Comment: 1) No process is 100% safe. The issue is balancing security needs with costs and the asylum seeker's human rights. 2) Politics 101: If you are an incumbent, saying that things are ok will give you few votes. It is always better to said that things (whatever) go horribly wrong (either if it is true or not) and that the country will plunge into chaos and anarchy if you are not elected.

Answer (score 1):

> If so what is the need for a stronger refugee laws and control?

The primary problem is that we don't have good sources for the data.  From your link:

> - The screening looks for indicators, like:
>
>   - Information that the individual is a security risk
>   - Connections to known bad actors
>   - Outstanding warrants/immigration or criminal violations

But where do we get that data?  It's not like the country they're fleeing would give us that kind of information even if it had it.  And it's not like the "bad actors" will tell us.

Basically we check to see if we've previously encountered the individual.  If we haven't, that person generally passes those checks.  The interviews are more likely to catch someone who has been radicalized without previous contact with us.  But they aren't perfect.

A side issue is the problem of radicalization in the United States.  This more often happens with the children of immigrants than with the immigrants themselves.  The children might be born in the United States.  No screening process will ever catch that.

Comment: The data problem is also a domestic one. State and Federal organizations have been working towards coordinating data among one another for years to ensure intelligence is shared among all governmental agencies in a secure way.